k8s apiserver connection timeout
I am using k8s version 1.28.2 with calico plugin. I am getting the below error while I am trying to schedule a pod in a particular node. All other nodes are working fine except this one.
Error from calico :

Failed to create pod sandbox: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to setup network for sandbox "5f54a7bdvergergerwv57f17ab804deab8f4d6fd60224c9be": plugin type="calico" failed (add): error getting ClusterInformation: Get "https://172.18.0.1:443/apis/crd.projectcalico.org/v1/clusterinformations/default": dial tcp 172.18.0.1:443: i/o timeout
"Container is getting created after sometime"

Error from pod description:

Failed to create pod sandbox: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to setup network for sandbox "5f54a7bdvergergerwv57f17ab804deab8f4d6fd60224c9be": plugin type="calico" failed (add): error getting ClusterInformation: Get "https://172.18.0.1:443/apis/crd.projectcalico.org/v1/clusterinformations/default": dial tcp 172.18.0.1:443: i/o timeout
Pod sandbox changed, it will be killed and re-created.

